# Use CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch name as a file path

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup a pipeline where the output will be written to a location based on the branch on which the pipeline was triggered.

Example: If branch was `topic/124579`,
then output must be written to `D:/Artifacts/topic/124579`.

But when I use this on my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, the runner creates a directory with the name `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` literally: `D:/Artifacts/CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`.

Here are a few things that I've tried

`md D:/Artifacts/CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` results in `D:/Artifacts/CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` as before

`md D:/Artifacts/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` results in `D:/Artifacts/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`

`md D:/Artifacts/"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"` also results in `D:/Artifacts/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`

How do I do this ?

I'm running my jobs on a self-hosted Windows runner, using `cmd` as the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first what [kind of shell you have set in your gitlab-ci](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/)

The default one would be [PowerShell Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#PowerShell_Core_6), in which case [variable substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#PowerShell_Core_6) should use `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`.
Try first `$env:CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`

But just in case you are using a deprecated CMD shell, try `"%CI_COMMIT_BRANCH%"`

---

The [OP rranjik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6885710/rranjik) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68506399/use-ci-commit-branch-branch-name-as-a-file-path/68506580#comment121072254_68506580):

> `md D:/Artifacts/"%CI_COMMIT_BRANCH%"` worked.

Comment: Thanks VonC! `md D:/Artifacts/"%CI_COMMIT_BRANCH%"` worked.